# Implementing onClickListener in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener, android-tablayout

I am updating an older Android application from using the no longer supported ViewPager and deprecated ActionBar to supported classes. I am having a difficult time implementing OnClickListeners in my fragments and creating views. Previously public class myFragment would extend Fragment and implement OnClickListener.

Below is what I have so far.

```
public class myFragment extends Fragment {
Button btnOne;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedDataEntryInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedDataEntryInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    fetchButtonClicks();
}

private void fetchButtonClicks(){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);

   btnOne = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnonexml);
   btnOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "BtnOne click event occurred.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Problem is in implementing the view in fetchButtonClicks().
**Two questions:** one, what am I missing here w/regards to view creation, and two, is there a better approach to structuring this? I have a dozen or so buttons in this fragment. Thanks in advance.

**Update:** Below code resolved my problem allowing OnClickListeners in Fragments. This is the structure I am going with based on responses. Seems to expand nicely to my many buttons.

```
public class dataEdit extends Fragment {
Button btnUpdateRecord, btnDeleteRecord, btnResetForm, btnFirstRecord, btnPreviousRecord,btnNextRecord, btnLastRecord, btnHelp, btnEditComment;
private Button btnSaveRecord = null; //Make above buttons private and equal null???
private View view = null;
private View v = null;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedDataEntryInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedDataEntryInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.data_edit, container, false);
    btnSaveRecord = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSaveRecordxml);
    btnUpdateRecord = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateRecordxml);
    btnDeleteRecord = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteRecordxml);
    btnResetForm = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnResetFormxml);
    btnFirstRecord = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnFirstRecordxml);
    btnPreviousRecord = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnPreviousRecordxml);
    btnNextRecord = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnNextRecordxml);
    btnLastRecord = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnLastRecordxml);
    btnHelp = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnDataEditHelpFilexml);
    btnEditComment = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnEditCommentxml);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    fetchButtonClicks();
} 

private void fetchButtonClicks(){
    btnSaveRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveRecord(v);
        }
    });
    btnUpdateRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            updateRecord(v);
        }
    });
    btnDeleteRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            deleteRecord(v);
        }
    });
    btnResetForm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            resetForm();
        }
    });
    btnFirstRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            firstRecord(v);
        }
    });
    btnPreviousRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            previousRecord(v);
        }
    });
    btnNextRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            nextRecord(v);
        }
    });
    btnLastRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            lastRecord(v);
        }
    });
    btnHelp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showHelpDialog();
        }
    });
    btnEditComment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showCommentEditDialog();
        }
    });
}
```

It's a work in progress at this point: additional suggestions welcome. Thanks.

Comment: the btnOne is on the Fragment layout ? i see that you have inflated two different view

Comment: Button is on the tab for that fragment. I've edited the example code to reflect this. Thanks for catching this.

Comment: AFAIK `ViewPager` isn't deprecated. Probably it's end of support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to **Inflate** The view two time just Pass the **View** into your `fetchButtonClicks`

```
private void fetchButtonClicks(View view){

   btnOne = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnonexml);
   btnOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "BtnOne click event occurred.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

and on your `onViewCreated()` method just call it like this :

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    fetchButtonClicks(view);
}
```

Comment: Get the following error in logcat, `code`     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at net.myCompany.myProgram.myFragment.fetchButtonClicks(myFragment.java:201)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:892)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)

Comment: can you update your a=question with my_fragment.xml

Comment: did you call the `fetchButtonClicks()` on the `onViewCreate()` or in `onCreateView()`

Comment: Initially from "OnViewCreate", I did just try it also from "OnCreateView" and got same logcat error. Thanks.

Comment: are you sure that the method is called ! please check it

Comment: I did. Logcat error is, "    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at net.myserver.myprogram.myfragment.fetchButtonClicks(myfragment.java:204)"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230866/discussion-between-shay-kin-and-portsample).

Answer (score 1):

That works

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);



    button =  (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnonexml);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("Klick");
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```